# Determine NSDate for Memorial Day in a given year

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

Is there a better way to determine the NSDate for Memorial Day (the last Monday in May) in a given year?

```
NSInteger aGivenYear = 2013 ;

NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar] ;
NSDateComponents* firstMondayInJuneComponents = [NSDateComponents new] ;
firstMondayInJuneComponents.month = 6 ;
// Thanks, Martin R., for pointing out that `weekOfMonth` is wrong for returning the first Monday in June.
firstMondayInJuneComponents.weekOfMonth = 1 ;
firstMondayInJuneComponents.weekday = 2 ; //Monday
firstMondayInJuneComponents.year = aGivenYear ;
NSDate* firstMondayInJune = [calendar dateFromComponents:firstMondayInJuneComponents] ;

NSDateComponents* subtractAWeekComponents = [NSDateComponents new] ;
subtractAWeekComponents.week = 0 ;
NSDate* memorialDay = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:subtractAWeekComponents toDate:firstMondayInJune options:0] ;
```

*Edit*

I see now that `firstMondayInJune` in the above example doesn't work for all years; it returns May 28 for the year 2012.

Thanks, [Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r). `weekdayOrdinal` does exactly what I hoped, and it returns Memorial Day with 3 fewer lines of code:

```
NSInteger aGivenYear = 2013 ;

NSDateComponents* memorialDayComponents = [NSDateComponents new] ;
memorialDayComponents.year = aGivenYear ;
memorialDayComponents.month = 5 ;
memorialDayComponents.weekday = 2 ; //Monday
memorialDayComponents.weekdayOrdinal = -1 ; //The last instance of the specified weekday in the specified month & year.
NSDate* memorialDay = [calendar dateFromComponents:memorialDayComponents] ;
```

Comment: I didn't check your algorithm, but I'd imagine that it will come down to something of roughly that complexity.  One can probably share some of the logic for calculating Labor Day, Thanksgiving, Birthington's Washday, etc.

Comment: Labor Day, Thanksgiving, and Presidents' Day are all simpler because their `weekOfMonth`s are plain ol' integers, while Memorial Day's depends on how many Mondays are in the month. Too bad...

Comment: But you can still use common logic for most of the calculation.  Or you can cheat and ask for the 5th Monday in May, and fall back to the 4th if that calculation chokes.

Comment: Ah, you're right. `weekOfMonth` doesn't work like I thought, so it doesn't calculate Labor Day, Thanksgiving, or President's Day very easily. I'll need some shared logic to figure out all four of them; I'll experiment some more.

Comment: What about Birthington's Washday?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the first Monday in a month, set `weekdayOrdinal = 1` instead of `weekOfMonth = 1`:

```
NSInteger aGivenYear = 2012 ;

NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar] ;
NSDateComponents* firstMondayInJuneComponents = [NSDateComponents new] ;
firstMondayInJuneComponents.month = 6 ;
firstMondayInJuneComponents.weekdayOrdinal = 1 ;
firstMondayInJuneComponents.weekday = 2 ; //Monday
firstMondayInJuneComponents.year = aGivenYear ;
NSDate* firstMondayInJune = [calendar dateFromComponents:firstMondayInJuneComponents] ;
// --> 2012-06-04

NSDateComponents* subtractAWeekComponents = [NSDateComponents new] ;
subtractAWeekComponents.week = -1 ;
NSDate* memorialDay = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:subtractAWeekComponents toDate:firstMondayInJune options:0] ;
// --> 2012-05-28
```

From the `NSDateComponents` documentation:

> Weekday ordinal units represent the position of the weekday within the
>   next larger calendar unit, such as the month. For example, ***2*** is the
>   weekday ordinal unit for the ***second*** Friday of the month.

Comment: Thanks, @Martin, `weekdayOrdinal` does exactly what I hoped, and it returns Memorial Day with 3 fewer lines of code. Although it's not documented, I was glad to find that a negative `weekdayOrdinal` counts backwards from the end of the month, which is perfect for determining Memorial Day.

Comment: +1 to you for doing some nice-looking (and correct) date calculations.

Comment: @DaveDeLong: Thanks (but the "nice look" is copied from the question, he only got `weekOfMonth` wrong :-) - Can you comment on John Sauer's observation on `weekdayOrdinal = -1`? Is that a reliable way of getting the *last* weekday in a month?

Comment: @DaveDeLong  I agree with MartinR that it'd be nice to hear from the horse's mouth about negative weekdayOrdinals. In the meantime, [my tests show them behaving as I'd hoped](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fYpBt.png).

Comment: My looks into the ICU documentation about this (which is what `NSCalendar` etc are built on) seem to indicate that negative ordinals are expected to work as you're seeing them here.

Answer (score -1):

What I'd probably do is get the day of the week of the first of the month (perhaps using NSDateFormatter), then calculate the date of the first Monday/Tuesday/Thursday/whatever of the month, then add (week# - 1) x 7 to that date to get the Nth Monday/whatever of the month.

For Memorial day you'd first check if the 5th Monday was still in May, if not use the 4th.  (Or check going in, knowing that if Memorial day is on the 31st then the first Monday must be on the 3rd or earlier.)