# Calculate number of weeks in a given month - Swift

Tags: swift, swift2

Having looked at a few different suggestions on SO, I've not been able to determine why the function below does not work. It seems to return 6 for some months and 5 for others. When changing weeks for days it works perfectly.

For example, trying

```
weeksInMonth(8, forYear 2015)
```

Results in 6.

I believe I have a mis-understanding of what 'firstWeekday' property on calendar does but haven't found an adequate explanation by Apple or online.

Have tried both .*WeekOfMonth* and .*WeekOfYear*. Again can't find explanation of exact difference.

Any suggestions would be greatly welcome.

```
func weeksInMonth(month: Int, forYear year: Int) -> Int?
{
    if (month < 1 || month > 12) { return nil }

    let dateString = String(format: "%4d/%d/01", year, month)
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
    if let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString),
       let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
    {
        calendar.firstWeekday = 2 // Monday
        let weekRange = calendar.rangeOfUnit(.WeekOfMonth, inUnit: .Month, forDate: date)
        let weeksCount = weekRange.length
        return weeksCount
    }
    else
    {
        return nil
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Apologies my question was not clear. I'm trying to work out how many weeks there are in a month that include a Monday in them. For August this should be 5.

Comment: There are six different weeks in August, 2015, so the result is correct, isn't it?

Comment: _yes_. I mean, _no_. well... _maybe_. I'm sorry... what is your question here?

Comment: Apologies, I've updated the question with my real question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code computes the number of weeks which occur (complete or partially)
in a month. What you apparently want is the number of Mondays
in the given month. With `NSDateComponents` and in particular with
the `weekdayOrdinal` property you can compute the first
(`weekdayOrdinal=1`) and last (`weekdayOrdinal=-1`) Monday
in a month. Then compute the difference in weeks (and add one).

A possible implementation in **Swift 2:**

```
func numberOfMondaysInMonth(month: Int, forYear year: Int) -> Int?
{
    let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
    calendar.firstWeekday = 2 // 2 == Monday

    // First monday in month:
    let comps = NSDateComponents()
    comps.month = month
    comps.year = year
    comps.weekday = calendar.firstWeekday
    comps.weekdayOrdinal = 1
    guard let first = calendar.dateFromComponents(comps)  else {
        return nil
    }

    // Last monday in month:
    comps.weekdayOrdinal = -1
    guard let last = calendar.dateFromComponents(comps)  else {
        return nil
    }

    // Difference in weeks:
    let weeks = calendar.components(.WeekOfMonth, fromDate: first, toDate: last, options: [])
    return weeks.weekOfMonth + 1
}
```

*Note:* That a negative `weekdayOrdinal` counts backwards from the end of the month is not apparent form the documentation. It was observed in
[Determine NSDate for Memorial Day in a given year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147450/determine-nsdate-for-memorial-day-in-a-given-year) and [confirmed by Dave DeLong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147450/determine-nsdate-for-memorial-day-in-a-given-year#comment19807427_14148014)).

---

Update for **Swift 3:**

```
func numberOfMondaysInMonth(_ month: Int, forYear year: Int) -> Int? {
    var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    calendar.firstWeekday = 2 // 2 == Monday

    // First monday in month:
    var comps = DateComponents(year: year, month: month,
                               weekday: calendar.firstWeekday, weekdayOrdinal: 1)
    guard let first = calendar.date(from: comps)  else {
        return nil
    }

    // Last monday in month:
    comps.weekdayOrdinal = -1
    guard let last = calendar.date(from: comps)  else {
        return nil
    }

    // Difference in weeks:
    let weeks = calendar.dateComponents([.weekOfMonth], from: first, to: last)
    return weeks.weekOfMonth! + 1
}
```

Comment: The code above: weeksInMonth(12,forYear: 2015) == 4, yet, there are 5 weeks in December, 2015.

Comment: @MikeChirico: The precise question was *"I'm trying to work out how many weeks there are in a month that include a Monday in them. For August this should be 5."* – December 2015 has 4 Mondays, so this is the result as requested here.

Comment: True.  "Given, how many weeks in a month that include Monday", that's a better answer.  And the example is instructive.

Comment: @MikeChirico: The question was initially unclear and clarified later in an update. I have renamed the function to avoid misunderstandings. Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 5):

Actually your question is : How many Mondays are in a given month?

My approach is to calculate the first Monday for the month, this can be accomplished by setting the CalendarUnit `WeekdayOrdinal` to 1. Then get the number of total days and do some math.

### Swift 1.2

```
func mondaysInMonth(month: Int, forYear year: Int) -> Int?
{
  if 1...12 ~= month {

    let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
    let components = NSDateComponents()
    components.weekday = 2 // Monday
    components.weekdayOrdinal = 1
    components.month = month
    components.year = year

    if let date = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)  {
      let firstDay = calendar.component(.CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: date)
      let days = calendar.rangeOfUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, inUnit:.CalendarUnitMonth, forDate:date).length
      return (days - firstDay) / 7 + 1
    }
  }
  return nil
}
```

### Swift 2

```
func mondaysInMonth(month: Int, forYear year: Int) -> Int?
{
  guard 1...12 ~= month else { return nil }

  let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
  let components = NSDateComponents()
  components.weekday = 2 // Monday
  components.weekdayOrdinal = 1
  components.month = month
  components.year = year

  if let date = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)  {
    let firstDay = calendar.component(.Day, fromDate: date)
    let days = calendar.rangeOfUnit(.Day, inUnit:.Month, forDate:date).length
    return (days - firstDay) / 7 + 1
  }
  return nil
}
```

Comment: 4 hours nothing and then 2 answers within 10 seconds :)

Comment: :-) I like your way to calculate also the last weekday of month.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 2**

The following code calculates the number of weeks in a month. It does not depend on what day the month started or ended.

```
func weeksInMonth(month: Int, year: Int) -> (Int)? {

  let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

  let comps = NSDateComponents()
  comps.month = month+1
  comps.year = year
  comps.day = 0

  guard let last = calendar.dateFromComponents(comps) else {
    return nil
  }
  // Note: Could get other options as well
  let tag = calendar.components([.WeekOfMonth,.WeekOfYear,
       .YearForWeekOfYear,.Weekday,.Quarter],fromDate: last)

  return tag.weekOfMonth

}

// Example Usage:

if let numWeeks = weeksInMonth(8,year: 2015) {
  print(numWeeks) // Prints 6
}

if let numWeeks = weeksInMonth(12,year: 2015) {
  print(numWeeks) // Prints 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Swift 4+:

```
//-- Get number of weeks from calendar
func numberOfWeeksInMonth(_ date: Date) -> Int {
     var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
     calendar.firstWeekday = 1
     let weekRange = calendar.range(of: .weekOfMonth,
                                    in: .month,
                                    for: date)
     return weekRange!.count
}

//-- Implementation
let weekCount = numberOfWeeksInMonth(Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4+:

Generate Date from your components:

```
let dateComponents = DateComponents.init(year: 2019, month: 5)
let monthCurrentDayFirst = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)!
let monthNextDayFirst = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: monthCurrentDayFirst)!
let monthCurrentDayLast = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: monthNextDayFirst)!
```

Detect week number from date:

```
let numberOfWeeks = Calendar.current.component(.weekOfMonth, from: monthCurrentDayLast)
```